# Division of data frames with conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data frames that looks something like:

```
df1 = 

date                    col1      col2      col3
------------------------------------------------
2022-08-17 00:00:00       50        30       -40
2022-08-17 01:00:00      100       -20        70
2022-08-17 02:00:00      180        10       -80
2022-08-17 03:00:00      -80       -66        20


df2 = 

date                    col1      col2      col3
------------------------------------------------
2022-08-17 00:00:00       50        33        90
2022-08-17 01:00:00       10        87        40
2022-08-17 02:00:00       70        90        30
2022-08-17 03:00:00       20        12        10


df3 = 

date                    col1      col2      col3
------------------------------------------------
2022-08-17 00:00:00      -50       -15       -40
2022-08-17 01:00:00     -120       -20       -70
2022-08-17 02:00:00     -160        -5       -80
2022-08-17 03:00:00      -40       -60       -20
```

So `df1` has a mix of positive and negative values, whereas `df2` only has positive values, and `df3` only negative.

What I would to do is doing some kind of division between the data frames. So for example:

```
df1 / df2  if df1_val > 0
-1 * df1 / df3  if df1_val < 0
```

So where the values in `df1` are negative then the corresponding value (index wise) in `df3` should be divided with the negative value in `df1`, and the other way around for `df2`.

Hence, the resulting data frame should in this case become:

```
df_result = 

date                    col1      col2      col3
------------------------------------------------
2022-08-17 00:00:00        1       0.9        -1
2022-08-17 01:00:00       10        -1      1.75
2022-08-17 02:00:00     2.57      0.11        -1
2022-08-17 03:00:00       -2      -1.1         2
```

Comment: 1) `date` is index or column? 2) Are the `date` equal among three dfs?

Comment: Date is not necessarily the index (but it could be if it makes it easier). And yes, the date is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the date as index on all dataframes

```
df1.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df2.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df3.set_index("date", inplace=True)
```

Then simply use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
result = (df1 / df2).where(df1>0, -df1/df3)
```

Arguably it is not terribly efficient since you always compute the divisions for both dataframes, but if your input dataset is small, it's the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`

```py
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
col = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1[cols] > 0,
                            df1[cols].div(df2[cols]),
                            -df1[cols].div(df3[cols])),
                   columns=cols)
out = df1[['date']].join(col)
```

```
print(out)

                  date       col1      col2  col3
0  2022-08-17 00:00:00   1.000000  0.909091 -1.00
1  2022-08-17 01:00:00  10.000000 -1.000000  1.75
2  2022-08-17 02:00:00   2.571429  0.111111 -1.00
3  2022-08-17 03:00:00  -2.000000 -1.100000  2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure pandas, it's always easier to have the ID columns as index:

```
(d1:=df1.set_index('date')).div(df2.set_index('date')).mask(d1.lt(0), -d1/df3.set_index('date'))
```

Output:

```
                          col1      col2  col3
date                                          
2022-08-17 00:00:00   1.000000  0.909091 -1.00
2022-08-17 01:00:00  10.000000 -1.000000  1.75
2022-08-17 02:00:00   2.571429  0.111111 -1.00
2022-08-17 03:00:00  -2.000000 -1.100000  2.00
```